# Nodejs require file depends on each other

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it normal to have `require` for each other in both files? I have a requirement where `AWS.js` is managed in a separate file but `AWS.js` needs variable from `index.js` and `index.js` imports `AWS.js`.

As you see in the below example, I might have to include require for each other. Any solution to this?

`index.js:`

I can't move these variables to `AWS.js` because the `event.Records[0].Sns.Message` belongs to a function in `index.js`

```
var AWS = require('./AWS.js');

var sns = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
var sns_MetricName = sns.Trigger.MetricName;
var sns_NameSpace = sns.Trigger.Namespace;
```

`AWS.js:`

```
if(sns_NameSpace == "AWS/S3") {
  keyFilter = ["BucketName", "StorageType"]
}
```

Workaround is to have both require each other. Any solution to this? Is this normal approach?

`index.js:`

```
var AWS = require('./AWS.js');

var sns = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
var sns_MetricName = sns.Trigger.MetricName;
var sns_NameSpace = sns.Trigger.Namespace;

exports.sns = sns;
exports.sns_MetricName = sns_MetricName;
exports.sns_NameSpace = sns_NameSpace;
```

`AWS.js:`

```
var index = require('./index.js');


if(index.sns_NameSpace == "AWS/S3") {
  keyFilter = ["BucketName", "StorageType"]
}
```

Comment: It looks like you don't need to require `'./AWS.js'` in index.js.

Comment: I need it. I have a function in `index.js` which will call the `AWS.js` if conditions

Comment: Well, that is not visible in the code snippet you show. Cyclical requires may not be a problem at all, or you may need to refactor your modules. That is something only you can decide, because others don't see your full code.

Comment: This is not supported in node.js. If you try to run this you will find node reporting an error and refusing to execute your code.

Comment: @slebetman Have you ever tried it? Modules *can* be recursively required, and if the exports are set before being used, you won't even get runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

Inject your dependencies. If AWS requires `sns_NameSpace` give it `sns_NameSpace`, don't import `index`:

AWS.js:

```
var keyFilter;

function init (sns_NameSpace) {
    if(sns_NameSpace == "AWS/S3") {
        keyFilter = ["BucketName", "StorageType"]
    }
}

exports.init = init;
exports.keyFilter = keyFilter;
```

index.js:

```
var AWS = require('./AWS.js');

var sns = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
var sns_MetricName = sns.Trigger.MetricName;
var sns_NameSpace = sns.Trigger.Namespace;

AWS.init(sns_NameSpace); // <------- Pass the value HERE!!

console.log(AWS.keyFilter); // <---- Prints ["BucketName","StorageType"]

exports.sns = sns;
exports.sns_MetricName = sns_MetricName;
exports.sns_NameSpace = sns_NameSpace;
```

Comment: I also need `keyFilter` exported. I tried using `exports.keyFilter` but that variable shows as undefined in index.js

Comment: It will show `undefined` before you call init because when we do `var keyFilter;` it is the same as doing `var keyFilter = undefined;` because `undefined` is the default value of uninitialized variables. However immediately after calling `AWS.init()` its value will not be `undefined`.